# Angular: Cannot start service: Host version "0.14.11" does not match binary version "0.14.22"

Tags: angular, compiler-errors

So when I am trying to compile my angular code (ng build) I get this error:

```
Cannot start service: Host version "0.14.11" does not match binary version "0.14.22"

1 error
⠼ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:156:25)
    at writevGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:139:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:785:11)
    at Socket._writev (net.js:794:8)
    at doWrite (internal/streams/writable.js:375:12)
    at clearBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:521:5)
    at onwrite (internal/streams/writable.js:430:7)
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:103:10)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  errno: -4047,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

I've found nothing about this problem in the interne

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 7):

It's an old question, but I'm answering it because it's on top of results in search.

I experienced the same issue; Removing node_modules and running `npm install`  helped.

Comment: A year later. Got the same error while upgrading from 0.18.16 to 0.19.5. 
Removing `node_modules` solved it indeed.